# Multiple collection using in same table

Tags: angularjs, html, mongodb, mean-stack

I have multiple collections like objectives and initiative etc... I want output like this using angular

[I want output like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2j5V2.jpg)

My sample collection data is :

```
$scope.objectives = [
  {id:1, name:"Objective 1"},
  {id:2, name:"Objective 2"},
  {id:3, name:"Objective 3"}
]

$scope.initiatives = [
  {id:1, name:"Initiative 1"},
  {id:2, name:"Initiative 2"},
  {id:3, name:"Initiative 3"}
]
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please have a look at some helpful tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - asking a good question improves your chances of getting an answer. 
But it is also equally important that you search first and do some research before posting your question. Also include what you have tried and indicate the problem(s) you are experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood you need something like

```
    <div ng-controller="Main">
      <div class="column">
        <p>Objectives</p>
        <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="obj in objectives">
          {{obj.name}}
        </li>
      </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <p>Initiatives</p>
        <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="ins in initiatives">
          {{ins.name}}
        </li>
      </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Here is Demo https://plnkr.co/edit/IhHnuWtFNnWsMkuYrVyD?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to ishmaelMakitla's comment since your question is not complete enough to really help us understand your problem.

From what I can read here, what you're looking for is the ngRepeat directive. [AngularJS API: ngRepeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat), here's the link.

You would then have a structure that could look like this:

```
$scope.collection = [
  {
    objective: "Some text"
    measures: "Some useful data"
    initiatives: "a list of things"
  },
  {
    objective: "Second item"
    measures: "Second useful data"
    initiatives: "another list of things"
  }
]
```

And in your html file:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in collection">
    <span class="column1>{{ item.objetive }}</span>
    <span class="column2>{{ item.measures }}</span>
    <span class="column3>{{ item.initiatives }}</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This allows you to loop through your collection (ngRepeat) according to the data in your controller ($scope) and using the template in the html file.

If you have 3 different collections which are not merged like this data structure, your should think about a way to structure your data the right way. But since this most probably comes from a database, you should be able to structure your data in this way without any major problems.